# backbone model to have property of another backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I don't know if this is supported in JS/Backbone, but if I have a backbone model, can I use that as a property for another backbone model?

e.g.

```
var Address = Backbone.Model.extend({
  street: ''
});

var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  name: '',
  Address: ''
});

var p1 = new Person();
p1.set('name', 'crystal');
console.log(p1.get('name'));
p1.set('Address.street', '1234');
console.log(p1.get('Address.street'));
```

Is this how Backbone is supposed to be used to compose objects?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [Backbone-Relational](http://backbonerelational.org/).

It adds support for nested bi-directional relationships between models such as one-to-one, one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the `address` entry in `Person` model a new instance of `Address` model?

e.g.

```
var Address = Backbone.Model.extend({
  street: ''
});

var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  name: '',
  address: null
});

var p = new Person;
p.set('address', new Address({street: 'crystal'}));
p.get('address').get('street');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can set a model attribute with any JavaScript valid object including a Backbone model object. But be aware of avoiding nesting models too deep because you don't want a deep property accessing chain which requires you do null check for each level accessing:

`p.get('parent').get('child').get('child').get('child').get('prop');`